# OpenVPN - How to ignore domain resolving for route-nopull while connecting?

Tags: openvpn

I'm using `route-nopull` feature, so only selected websites use VPN.

So far, so good. But when I add a website that is blocked by my ISP or temporarily unavailable, I can't even make the OpenVPN connection, it hangs.

I suspect it happens because it can't ping the new IP it so it tries again, how can I stop this check while connecting? If I remove the new rule, I can connect, so that's what causing the issue here.

OpenVPN version

> OpenVPN 2.4.7 x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4]
>   [PKCS11] [MH/RECVDA] [AEAD] built on Apr 18 2019

I'm on MacOS.

.ovpn config

```
# VPN configuration generator
# Location: norway
# Protocol: udp
# Port: 1194
# DNS-leak protection: no

client
dev tun
proto udp
remote vpnremoteaddressishere 1194
resolv-retry infinite
auth-user-pass
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
reneg-sec 0
keepalive 10 60


mute-replay-warnings
explicit-exit-notify 3

cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA512
tls-version-min 1.2

<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
certificateishere
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

</ca>

key-direction 1
<tls-auth>
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
statickeyishere
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----

</tls-auth>

verb 3
route-nopull 
route www.whatsmyip.org 255.255.255.255
```

whatsmyip.org returns VPN's IP.
ip-tracker.org returns my real IP, so everything works as expected.

But after adding imgur.com as a route (it's blocked by my ISP), I can't re-establish the OpenVPN connection and that's a catch-22.

What can I do here?